# Switch between two functions to the same link

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see I'm trying to make Show more/less button.

1. I made the paragraph to be collapsed as a default status.
2. Click on the "Show more" button to expand the paragraph.
3. The paragraph is expanded.
4. click on the show less button **doesn't work**

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <!--Start Para-->
    <div class="para">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, libero voluptatem sunt voluptate est sint, laboriosam ab facilis recusandae dolorem fuga accusamus, aperiam nam sequi veniam. Provident fugit nobis adipisci consequatur beatae, perspiciatis molestias quam officiis odit consectetur! Sapiente, tempore, nesciunt. Recusandae assumenda natus iste placeat illo. Dignissimos ea, sed suscipit asperiores quidem alias quam earum, tempore, nihil eius aliquam sit, accusantium enim at! Exercitationem nesciunt deleniti, ipsa aut ab rerum, harum voluptatem dolore optio architecto dolores? Fugit id ipsam sit dolores distinctio. Aliquam dolores aliquid sit soluta error ut magnam minima animi qui necessitatibus! Sequi quae, expedita iusto dolorem.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, libero voluptatem sunt voluptate est sint, laboriosam ab facilis recusandae dolorem fuga accusamus, aperiam nam sequi veniam. Provident fugit nobis adipisci consequatur beatae, perspiciatis molestias quam officiis odit consectetur! Sapiente, tempore, nesciunt. Recusandae assumenda natus iste placeat illo. Dignissimos ea, sed suscipit asperiores quidem alias quam earum, tempore, nihil eius aliquam sit, accusantium enim at! Exercitationem nesciunt deleniti, ipsa aut ab rerum, harum voluptatem dolore optio architecto dolores? Fugit id ipsam sit dolores distinctio. Aliquam dolores aliquid sit soluta error ut magnam minima animi qui necessitatibus! Sequi quae, expedita iusto dolorem.</p>
    </div> <!--END para-->
</div> <!--END wrapper-->
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mainPara = $(".para").children("p"),
        longPara = mainPara.html().substr(0),
        shortPara = mainPara.html().substr(0, 380);
    mainPara.html(shortPara).append("...<a class='linkBtn more' href='#'>show more</a>");

    $(".linkBtn").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).parent().html(longPara).append("<a class='linkBtn less' href='#'>show less</a>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the event binded to show less button?

Comment: `mainPara.html(shortPara)` sets the HTML of all the paragraphs to the same thing. Is that really what you want?

Comment: I want to switch between "shortPara" & "longPara"
I can't do it with The if statement. Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bit of misconception here, you are not maintaining uniqueness by paragraph since you are only saving the html of the first one in you vars.

What you need to do is loop through the paragraphs and let each one know what long and short text it has. This is the role of `data` function in my code.

You also need to use event delegation with jquery `on` in order to bind click events to the dynamically added show more/less links.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".para").children("p").each(function(index,item)
  {
      var shortText = $(this).html().substr(0, 380);
      var originalText = $(this).html();
    
      if(originalText.length > 380)
      {
        // save the original paragraph html in the paragraph data
        $(this).data('long_p', originalText);
        $(this).data('short_p', shortText);
        
        $(this).html(shortText + "...<a class='linkBtn more' href='#'>show more</a>");
      }
     
    }); 
    
     
    $('p').on('click','.linkBtn', function(){
    
        var para = $(this).closest('p');
      
        if($(this).hasClass('more'))
        {
          
            para.html(para.data("long_p") + "...<a class='linkBtn less' href='#'>show less</a>");
        }
        else
        {
             para.html(para.data("short_p") + "...<a class='linkBtn more' href='#'>show more</a>");         
        }
    
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <!--Start Para-->
    <div class="para">
        <p>No need for show more paragraph one</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, libero voluptatem sunt voluptate est sint, laboriosam ab facilis recusandae dolorem fuga accusamus, aperiam nam sequi veniam. Provident fugit nobis adipisci consequatur beatae, perspiciatis molestias quam officiis odit consectetur! Sapiente, tempore, nesciunt. Recusandae assumenda natus iste placeat illo. Dignissimos ea, sed suscipit asperiores quidem alias quam earum, tempore, nihil eius aliquam sit, accusantium enim at! Exercitationem nesciunt deleniti, ipsa aut ab rerum, harum voluptatem dolore optio architecto dolores? Fugit id ipsam sit dolores distinctio. Aliquam dolores aliquid sit soluta error ut magnam minima animi qui necessitatibus! Sequi quae, expedita iusto dolorem.123</p>
        <p><b>I am a unique paragraph and my text shall stay unique.</b> Rem, libero voluptatem sunt voluptate est sint, laboriosam ab facilis recusandae dolorem fuga accusamus, aperiam nam sequi veniam. Provident fugit nobis adipisci consequatur beatae, perspiciatis molestias quam officiis odit consectetur! Sapiente, tempore, nesciunt. Recusandae assumenda natus iste placeat illo. Dignissimos ea, sed suscipit asperiores quidem alias quam earum, tempore, nihil eius aliquam sit, accusantium enim at! Exercitationem nesciunt deleniti, ipsa aut ab rerum, harum voluptatem dolore optio architecto dolores? Fugit id ipsam sit dolores distinctio. Aliquam dolores aliquid sit soluta error ut magnam minima animi qui necessitatibus! Sequi quae, expedita iusto dolorem.456</p>
    </div> <!--END para-->
</div> <!--END wrapper-->
```